# How can I add this USB Printer (`/dev/usb/lp0`) to printer list when print command is given in any application?

Tags: usb, printing

I have made a USB thermal printer which generates the `/dev/usb/lp0` nod in `/dev` folder.

Printing using `echo "Test PrintSlip" /dev/usb/lp0` works fine. I would also want to print from text editors using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, which doesn't work currently.

How can I add this USB Printer (`/dev/usb/lp0`) to printer list when print command is given in any application?

Answer (score 0):

Install the printer using the

> Printers

Window: Dash -> Printers -> Add Printer.

[image]

Depending on the printer, you may need to download the right drivers.

Regards.